# Can someone help me figure out this complex number problem?

Tags: complex-numbers

I don't understand how to do this.

If $i^2 = -1$, $(4 + i)^2$ = ?

Comment: Just square the binomial using the usual rules of algebra and end with something of the form $a + bi$.

Comment: just apply $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(4+i)^2 = (4+i)\cdot (4+i)$$

Now... recall your "FOIL" (*firsts, outers, inners, lasts*) technique of how to multiply two sums together... that is, $(a+b)(c+d) = ac+ad+bc+bd$.  The same works here even though these are complex numbers and not integers like you might have been used to working with up until now.

$$(4+i)\cdot (4+i)=4\cdot 4 + 4\cdot i + i\cdot 4 + i\cdot i$$

Now, you just use that $i^2=-1$ to simplify the last term and then combine like-terms to finish:

> $$4\cdot 4 + 4\cdot i + i\cdot 4 + i\cdot i = 16 + 4i + 4i -1 = 15 + 8i$$

---

As an aside, "FOIL" was how we were taught originally, but it is merely a double-application of the distributivity property of multiplication over addition, that $x(y+z) = xy + xz$ and that $(x+y)z=xz+yz$.

Here, treating $(a+b)$ as a term by itself, we have $(a+b)(c+d) = (a+b)c + (a+b)d$ and then using distributivity again from the other side $ = ac+bc+ad+bd$